# Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions Building native extensions

Tags: react-native, bundle, ffi, bundle-install

**Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions Building native extensions**

[image]

Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Building native extensions with: '--enable-system-libffi'
This could take a while...
Bundler::InstallError: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
cocoapods was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
typhoeus was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
ethon was resolved to 0.16.0, which depends on
ffi

Installing ffi 1.15.5`

Answer (score 0):

bundle config --local build.ffi --with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration

bundle install

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space between your username on system. I use Win11, I'm not sure how this works, but renaming the username works.

Will share the reference answer & my logs soon

Mine was "DB Studios" & I renamed to "DB_Studios"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in your folder path.

for eg: my path was : `/users/sridhar/source code`

I changed it to: `/users/sridhar/source_code`